# ValueError: truth value of array is ambiguous

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

The code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

    r = np.linspace(0.02, 0.98, 10)
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
    rgrid, thetagrid = np.meshgrid(r, theta)

    xgrid, ygrid = rgrid*np.cos(thetagrid), rgrid*np.sin(thetagrid)

    def get_zvalue(r):
        if r<0.03:
            return 0
        elif r>0.02:
            delta_s = 0.02/np.sqrt(1-(r-0.02)**2)
            return delta_s + get_zvalue(r-0.02)

    zsurface = get_zvalue(r)



    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    surf = ax.plot_surface(xgrid, ygrid, zsurface)
    plt.savefig("Hoops.png")
```

The error:

```
    ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is 
    ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The ValueError is triggered by the line, "if r<0.03:" in the function get_zvalue. I haven't done much with numpy and don't know what to make of this error. Is there any other way to create the zsurface array without getting the error?

Comment: If `r` is an array, then `r<0.3` is also an array.  `if` expects one True/False value.  It can't work with an array of them.